# how to search for document in an array and delete it?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, firestorter

I am trying to create adding to favorite button, I'am able to add object to an array but for some reason I cannot delete it from the array. How to remove it from the array? .Here is my code. thanks

```
func didClickFavoriteButton(item: Item) { 

// removing from favorite (not working)

 if user.favoritCar.contains(item.id!)  {
 let index = user.favoritCar.firstIndex(of:item.id!)
 user.favoritCar.remove(at: index!)

FirebaseReference(.User).document(kFAVORIT).updateData([kFAVORIT : 
FieldValue.arrayRemove(user.favoritCar)])

} else { 

// Adding to favorite                   

user.favoritCar.append(item.id!)
      FirebaseReference(.User).document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).updateData([kFAVORIT : FieldValue.arrayUnion(user.favoritCar)])

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
if let temp = user.favoritCar.first(where: {$0.id == item.id}) {
   if let index = user.favoritCar.firstindex(of: temp) {
      user.favoritCar.remove(at: index)
   }
}
```

Instead of this code:

```
if user.favoritCar.contains(item.id!)  {
 let index = user.favoritCar.firstIndex(of:item.id!)
 user.favoritCar.remove(at: index!)
```